# Tensorflow GANs discriminator doesn't learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to make a basic GAN that tries to learn a simple 3 by 3 matrix with a plus in it.

However, for some reason, the discriminator loss doesn't change.

For example:

> ```
> [[0.0, 0.98, 0,01]
>
> [0.95, 0.97, 0.99]
>
> [0.02, 0.99, 0.02]]
> ```

Here is the code:

GENERATOR AND DISCRIMINATOR:

```
def make_generator():
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(5, )))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((3, 3)))
    return model


def make_discriminator():
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=[3, 3]))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
    return model

generator = make_generator()
discriminator = make_discriminator()
```

I think that the problem lies in the training, but I'm not sure.

The training program:

```
generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.1)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.1)

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)


def generator_loss(generated_im):
    loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(generated_im), generated_im)
    return loss


def discriminator_loss(real_im_pred, generated_im_pred):
    loss_on_real = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_im_pred), real_im_pred)
    loss_on_generated = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(generated_im_pred), generated_im_pred)
    loss = loss_on_generated + loss_on_real
    return loss

@tf.function
def train_step(images, batch_size):
        
    noise = tf.random.normal([batch_size, 5])
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
        classification_on_real = discriminator(images, training=True)
        classification_on_fake = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)
        
        gen_loss = generator_loss(generated_images)
        disc_loss = discriminator_loss(classification_on_real, classification_on_fake)

        gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
        gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
    
    return gen_loss, disc_loss
        
def train(data, epochs, batch_size):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        start = time.time()
        
        # Keep track of the total loss and accuracy
        total_gen_loss = 0
        total_disc_loss = 0
        
        for image_batch in data:
            gen_loss, disc_loss = train_step(image_batch, batch_size)
            
            total_gen_loss += gen_loss
            total_disc_loss += disc_loss
            
        print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec, generator loss: {}, discriminator loss: {}'
               .format(epoch + 1, round(time.time()-start), round(float(total_gen_loss), 2), round(float(total_disc_loss), 2)))
```

The output I get when running this code is the following:

```
Time for epoch 1 is 3 sec, generator loss: 346.15, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 2 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.61, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 3 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.33, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 4 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.24, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 5 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.19, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 6 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.16, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 7 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.14, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 8 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.13, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 9 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.12, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 10 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.11, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 11 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.11, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 12 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.11, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 13 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.1, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 14 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.1, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 15 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.1, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 16 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.1, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 17 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.09, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 18 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.09, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 19 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.09, discriminator loss: 3252.97
Time for epoch 20 is 2 sec, generator loss: 308.09, discriminator loss: 3252.97
```

If you're interested in the code for making the data, here it is:

```
def plus():
    array = np.array([[np.random.normal(0.05, 0.01, 1)[0], np.random.normal(0.95, 0.01, 1)[0], np.random.normal(0.05, 0.01, 1)[0]],
                     [np.random.normal(0.95, 0.01, 1)[0], np.random.normal(0.95, 0.01, 1)[0], np.random.normal(0.95, 0.01, 1)[0]],
                     [np.random.normal(0.05, 0.01, 1)[0], np.random.normal(0.95, 0.01, 1)[0], np.random.normal(0.05, 0.01, 1)[0]]])
    return array


def dataset(size):
    X = []
    
    for _ in range(size):
        x = plus()
        X.append(x)
    return np.array(X)


def get_batches(x, batch_size):
    batches = []
    for i in range(0, x.shape[0], batch_size):
        batch = x[i:i + batch_size]
        batches.append(batch)
    
    random.shuffle(batches)
    return np.array(batches)

BATCH_SIZE = 10
data = dataset(20000)
data = get_batches(data, BATCH_SIZE)
```

I hope you can help!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to use `sigmoid` activation for the discriminator output, not `softmax`. Softmax for a single output unit doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> The Activation function to be used in the last layer of the `Discriminator` should be `Sigmoid`, instead of `Softmax`, as the `Final Dense Layer` of the `Discriminator` has only 1 `Node/Neuron/Unit`.
> (paraphrased from xdurch0).

Comment: If you are going to take content from comments wholesale, you should mark your answer as a Community Wiki and also embed the answer you've copied in a blockquote. I'll do the latter, but the former has to be done by you.

Comment: @TylerH, Marked the Answer as Community Wiki. Thank you for your feedback.